# How to write and read from a file in android

Tags: java, android, file

I am having some issues with writing and reading with android. 
here is my code:

```
package filereader.testing.com;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FileReaderTestingActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button submit_btn =  (Button) findViewById (R.id.submit_btn);
        final EditText textbox = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.first_text);
        final TextView newtext = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.read_text);
        submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    byte[] readinfo = new byte[3];
                    String FILENAME = "first_file";
                FileOutputStream mystream;
            try {
                mystream = openFileOutput (FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String variabletowrite = textbox.toString();
                mystream.write(variabletowrite.getBytes());
                mystream.close();
                FileInputStream readstream = openFileInput (FILENAME);
                readstream.read(readinfo);
                newtext.setText(readinfo.toString());
                readstream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the try and catch was added by eclipse

here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
/>
<EditText android:id="@+id/first_text" android:layout_width="match_parent"       
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Submit"     
android:id="@+id/submit_btn" android:layout_width="match_parent"></Button>
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/read_text" android:layout_weight="0.12" android:layout_width="280dp"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="filereader.testing.com"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
    <activity android:name=".FileReaderTestingActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

when I run the code all of the text boxes appear and so does the submit button, but when I type something in and then hit the submit button the text box changes to things like [B@40532d08 and I have no idea what it means. the number seems to count up every time that I click the submit button and the [B@ part never changes, just the numbers and letters after it.

any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line...

```
String variabletowrite = textbox.toString();
```

to...

```
String variabletowrite = textbox.getText().toString();
```

The first line (the way you are doing it) is calling `toString()` on the `EditText` object itself (i.e., it's reference) and not its text contents.

**EDIT**
When setting the text for the `TextView` this line...

```
newtext.setText(readinfo.toString());
```

is also simply converting your `byte[]` reference to a string. You need to do something like the following to create a string from an array of bytes...

```
newtext.setText(new String(readinfo));
```

Comment: @Phoenix: See the EDIT to my answer.